# Error when trying to JOIN two derived tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I'm going nuts trying to figure out this error. I am working in MySQL and need to join two derived tables on a common column. All columns in the two tables are aliased as are the tables.

Scheme is

`stops (id, name)`

`route (num, company, pos, stop)` where

`stops.id` <---> `route.stop`

These tables contain bus routes between cities and I want to figure out all the routes from 'Craiglockhart' to 'Sighthill' which require exactly two buses (i.e., a transfer point). Moreover, because the `route` table doesn't contain stop names (only ID's), we use some joins inside the derived tables to refer to stops by name; this is just a convenience)

So I tried to make two derived tables. One of all the routes that can take a person between 'Craiglockhart' and any station which is not 'Craighartlock' and an identical second derived table but for 'Sighthill'. I was able to get both such tables to work separately.

But, when I tried to join them along the common column of the so-called transfer station (i.e., the non-Craighartlock station in the first table and the non-Sighthill station in the second), I get an error.

**Derived Table 1**: This works fine and returns the table correctly. here, `stop_b.name` represents the transfer station which is not Craiglockhart and `stop_a.name` represents the Craighill "starting" station.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Craiglockhart') AS first_route
```

**Derived Table 2**: SAME THING but different table alias and station restriction. Here `stop_b.name` represents the transfer station (which is not Sighthill) and `stop_a.name` represents the Sighthill "ending" station.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Sighthill' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Sighthill') AS second_route
```

But, when I try to join these along their common `name_transfer' column (alias for stop_b.name in both) I get an error:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Craiglockhart') AS first_route
JOIN

(SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Sighthill' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Sighthill') AS second_route)

ON (first_route.name_transfer = second_route.name_transfer)
)
```

I also tried replacing `ON` with `USING (name_transfer)` since the column I want to join the derived tables on is called that in both of the derived tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to put parentheses around the `SELECT` after `JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar: even when I add parentheses around the second big SELECT I get the "every dervied table must have an alias" error. In my edit above I put the new closing parenthesis after the alias for the second derived table but I get the same error if I move this to before "AS second_route". Do i need to give an alias to the JOIN? Would that go after the last (main) "ON"?

Comment: You need to give an alias to that new `SELECT`, e.g. `JOIN (SELECT * ...) AS second_route`. You have the alias in the nested subquery, not the subquery you're joining with.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have those `SELECT *` queries wrapped around the inner subqueries.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT blah, blah ...)` is the same as `SELECT blah, blah, ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parentheses around a subquery when you use it in a `FROM` or `JOIN` clause. You have it in the `FROM` clause, but not in the `JOIN` clause. The problem seems to have come when you added the unnecessary `SELECT * FROM SELECT` around each subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Craiglockhart') AS first_route
JOIN

    (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
            stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
               route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                    JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                    JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                    WHERE stop_a.name = 'Sighthill' AND 
                          stop_b.name <> 'Sighthill') AS second_route

ON first_route.name_transfer = second_route.name_transfer
```

Comment: thanks for your help but this is still giving me an error "near" the last `ON`. I tried exactly your code....

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle so I can try it out?

Comment: Wait, nm, it works, I think I had a little typo. Thanks @Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
                stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
                   route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                        JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                        JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                        WHERE stop_a.name = 'Craiglockhart' AND 
                              stop_b.name <> 'Craiglockhart') AS first_route) AS A
    JOIN

    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT a.num AS num_a, a.company AS comp_a, stop_a.name AS name_a, 
                stop_b.name AS name_transfer FROM
                   route a JOIN route b ON (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
                        JOIN stops stop_a ON (a.stop=stop_a.id)
                        JOIN stops stop_b ON (b.stop=stop_b.id)
                        WHERE stop_a.name = 'Sighthill' AND 
                              stop_b.name <> 'Sighthill') AS second_route)B
    ON (A.name_transfer = B.name_transfer)
```